# What does it mean "internal compiler error: storage failure" on UNIX?

Tags: c++, unix, compiler-errors, cc

I have to build an application on UNIX, Unixware 2.1.3, with a CCS compiler 3.0 and I keep having this error :

```
UX:acomp: ERROR: "//home/dino/treeit.h", line 32: internal compiler error:  storage failure
*** Error code 1 (bu21)
UX:make: ERROR: fatal error.
```

**I've look at the space available on my system and it's fine.**

Here's the code section, in c++, from line 23 to 36 :

```
public:

    bool operator != (iterator_impl const &p_iterator) const
    {
        return m_pNode != p_iterator.m_pNode;
    }

    __BTL_ITERATOR_IMPL_NAME()
        :m_pNode(0)
    {} //Line 32 is here!!!!!!!

    __BTL_ITERATOR_IMPL_NAME(iterator_impl const &p_iterator)
        :m_pNode(p_iterator.m_pNode)
    {}
```

I'm not that good on UNIX and don't know if it's a operating system related problem. Can someone help me ? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I can only think it comes from a lack of disk space. Please check how it evolves when you're compiling. Also, what compiler and version?

Comment: Running out of disk space seems to be the most reasonable thing. You said that you checked for disk space, but just make sure that you not only check for sufficient disk space on the file system where your sources are (and where the output is supposed to be written), but also for sufficient space on `/tmp` (or where your `TMP` environment variable points to).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. I've added the compiler version and found the exact Unixware version.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to mean you're out of disk space during the compilation:

http://www.linuxmisc.com/4-linux/7e5b068dd5eedb04.htm

Comment: Yes, that is the one hit that Google comes up with. However, note that the authors in this thread mix GCC with Unixware's C compiler during the discussion. So, while "out of free space" seems indeed reasonable, I would take that discussion/link with a grain of salt.